# Is ObjectSID a feature of Active Directory or is it a standard feature of all directories?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap, apache-ds

Is ObjectSID a feature of Active Directory or is it a standard feature of all directories? Is there an Object Class that provides `ObjectSID` which can be used in other directory services such as OpenLDAP or ApacheDS?

Comment: TL;DR: No, it's a Windows/AD feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `objectSID` - the [`Security Identifier`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - is a **Windows NT**-thing, not a generic **directory service**-thing.

[Version 3.0](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/3.0:_Initialization_LDAP_Database) (and newer) of the [Samba project](https://www.samba.org/)'s LDAP schema contains a fully compatible attribute class called `sambaSID`, intended to store and display SID's just like the `objectSID` class.